# Hive Regular Expression

Tags: regex, hadoop, plsql, hive

Can any one let me know how to use the regular expression in Hive latest versions in one scenario.I have one column with different values-many rows and i want to extract data after after val data as below

col1   ->   Money;valone:this is savings account

col2   ->   Money;valtwo:Not a general account

col3   ->   Money;valthree:your credit card

col4   ->  Money;valFour:incorrect acctnumber

when i do select query using regular expression

select colname,regexp_extract(colname,*.;val?:[^...,1) from hive_table;

I want  the output as 
Output: 
this is savings account
Not a general account
your credit card
incorrect acctnumber

---

I also tried                                                   valone|valtwo|valthree|valfour....
but there are almost thousands of records which i cannot write valone|valtwo|valthree|valfour .................................               for each record.

Can any one help on this?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is problem with your regexp.Please try following query.

```
select colname,regexp_extract(colname,'.*;.*:(.*)',1) from table_name;
```